# Celery is executing tasks every second for a once a year crontab

Tags: django, celery, djcelery

I'm trying to get a task to run at the end of the day on 1/1. So, I wrote this:

```
@periodic_task(run_every = crontab(
    day_of_month=1, month_of_year=1, hour=23, minute=51)
)
def tell_admins_about_completed_updates():
    logging.info('Updates to period instances are complete', extra={
            'tell_admins': True,
            'email_content': 'Please check that new instances are displaying '
                'properly'
        }
    )
```

With the crontab as is, I see this task running every second. If I change the value of hour to 0 I don't see it execute (presumably because it's not the right time). Has anyone else observed this behavior? Am I missing something fundamental?

**EDIT**: I checked again. It seems like the behavior changes if I change `month_of_year` (not `hour`) as I suggested above. To be clear, if the crontab is configured with `day_of_month=31, month_of_year=12, hour=0, minute=49` it appears to work (i.e., I don't see the task running every second). If the crontab is configured with `day_of_month=31, month_of_year=1, hour=0, minute=49` it does not work (i.e., I see the task running every second). Very odd...